# XML for add Profiles to <isAdditionalPermissionRequiredToRun>true</isAdditionalPermissionRequiredToRun>

Tags: salesforce

In salesforce DevOps Center is not working; I have to add profile to a flow Access
for admin and Customer Community Login User

isAdditionalPermissionRequiredToRun>true</isAdditionalPermissionRequiredToRun
My question :  true for profile Customer Community Login User

```
 </dynamicChoiceSets>
    <environments>Default</environments>
    <interviewLabel>nameOfFlow{!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}</interviewLabel>
    <isAdditionalPermissionRequiredToRun>true</isAdditionalPermissionRequiredToRun>
    <label>nameOfFlow</label>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>BuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
```

Thx in advance
I try deploy with SAlesforce devOp center; but settings regarding the profile was not in GitHub as expected

Answer (score 0):

The [Profile FlowAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm?q=profile#ProfileFlowAccess_title) is retrieved for any profiles that are retrieved along with [FlowDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flowdefinition.htm?q=flowdefinition) via the metadata API. Depending on your source control and deployment process, deploying with a FlowDefinition may cause issues with activation of an updated Flow, so you may want to:

- Avoid deploying with FlowDefinition and only use it to retrieve profile metadata configuration.

OR

- Manually code your profile xml flowAccesses

  ```
   <flowAccesses>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
       <flow>Flow_name</flow>
   </flowAccesses>
  ```

OR

- Consider flowAccesses a post-deployment step.